# How to simulate China network?

Tags: manual-testing

how to simulate China network environment?

Our app behave different under China environment.

I have tried vpn and it seems my router still able to detect that I'm not in China.

Any advise and recommendation how you guys test this kind of feature?

Comment: By China network environment you mean network conditions inside China?

Comment: @Mate yes, network.

Comment: How does your application detect "china network"?

Comment: What about you creating a build that exposes only the behavior of China, regardless of the real user location?

Comment: Please add more details like why app recognize your location as not china , even in VPN

Comment: I have not much tech details too how the app detected China network. Anybody experiences? I guess this is standard industry practice to build app cater for different market.

Comment: Unless you know the details you cannot be sure you've created a reliable test. Even if your guess will help you to reach the desired behavior, that won't mean you have covered all the possible ways the app detects the Chinese user. So since you're talking about testing (not about crawling, etc) the best way would be to contact developers.  The app can make its choice basing on set of parameters. IP is only one of criteria. It would be strange to show a foreign citizen Chinese page just because they are in China. Another way is to take user's locale and show localized version depending on it.